# How to Convert ViewBag Value to SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna to make a VieBage items as a select list in DropDown , this is my ViewModel content

```
 public List<SelectListItem> SelectedItemForRole { get; set; }

 public string SelectedValue { get; set; }




public static RegisterViewModel GetRole()
        {
            var model = new RegisterViewModel { SelectedItemForRole = new List<SelectListItem>() };
            model.SelectedItemForRole.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Administrator", Value = "1" });
            model.SelectedItemForRole.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Operator", Value = "2" });

            return model;
        }
```

this is my action content:

```
  ViewBag.RoleList = RegisterViewModel.GetRole();
```

and what I have done in View is like this :

```
 <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(register => register.Role)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(register => register.SelectedValue, new SelectList(ViewBag.RoleList, "Value", "Text"))
        </div>
```

but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is cast the ViewBag value as a SelectList. So in your case:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(register => register.SelectedValue, (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleList)
```

However when I look at your code I see that your ViewBag instance is of type RegisterViewModel which has a property named SelectedItemForRole which contains your select list. So then I think what you need is this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(register => register.SelectedValue, ((RegisterViewModel)ViewBag.RoleList).SelectedItemForRole)
```

Basically you cast your ViewBag into RegisterViewModel and then use the SelectedItemForRole for the SelectList.

Answer (score -1):

```
CType(ViewBag.Especialidades, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem))
```